# Full alphabetical order of strings javascript

Tags: javascript, function, alphabetical

do you know how can I alphabetically order all the strings of an array? I am using the localcompare function but when I have two strings that start with the same letter the function is not comparing the next letter after the first and just ordering them randomly. Thanks in advance.

```js
function solve(input) {
  let output = [];

  for (element of input) {
    let name = element.split(`,`)[0];
    if (!output.includes(element)) {
      output.push(name);
    }
    
    output
      .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
      .sort((a, b, ) => a.length - b.length)
  }
  
  return output;
}


let input = ["Ashton", "Kutcher", "Ariel", "Lilly", "Keyden", "Aizen", "Billy", "Braston"]

console.log(solve(input))
```

Comment: do you have an example with strings?

Comment: Including the code you are using would help illuminate your question.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5cYXwxDs 
Here is the function

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are you sorting by the `length` after `.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))`?

Comment: You should not put the `sort` inside the loop but after it. Also as adiga said, don't compare by length.

Comment: But I need them sorted by length as well

Comment: What? You can either sort the array in alphabetical order OR you can sort them by the length of each string. Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55220074/edit) the question and what output you're expecting for this input?

Answer (score 0):

**i hope this will help you,**

```
var arr = ["Ashton","Kutcher","Ariel","Lilly","Keyden","Aizen","Billy","Braston"];
console.log(arr.sort());
```